# Should similar questions, written in different languages, be marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I made [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/212/115) (in Portuguese) and it was marked as a duplicate. However, the question that is refers to is in another language (in English). In these cases, should the question be considered as a duplicate?

**Observation**: I checked if there already was a similar question in Portuguese, which is the language I use, before asking.

---

Fiz [essa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/212/115) (em português) e a mesma foi considerada com duplicada, porém a pergunta que foi referenciada está em outro idioma (em inglês), nesse caso a minha pergunta deve ser considera duplicada?

**Observação**: antes de fazer a pergunta verifiquei se já existia alguma semelhante em português, que é o idioma que utilizo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/), we consider two questions duplicates even if they are in different languages.

On French.SE, it is recommended but not mandatory that answers are in the same language as the question. So a question in language 1 may already have answers in language 2, perfectly suitable for a cross-language duplicate.

We encourage translating answers upon request. If someone asks in French and gets answers in French, then someone asks in English (or vice versa), we'll close the second question as a duplicate, but we'll make sure to edit the question and answers to add English translations.

---

No [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/), consideramos duas perguntas duplicadas mesmo se estiverem em idiomas diferentes.

No French.SE, é recomendado, mas não obrigatório, que as respostas respondam na mesma língua da pergunta. Portanto uma pergunta na língua 1 poderá já ter respostas na língua 2, perfeitamente adequadas para uma pergunta duplicada de outra língua.

Encorajamos a tradução de respostas por pedido. Se alguém pergunta em francês e obtém respostas em francês, e depois alguém pergunta em inglês (ou vice versa), fechamos a segunda pergunta como duplicada, mas também fazemos garantir que a primeira pergunta e respostas sejam editadas para incluir traduções em inglês.

Comment: Na minha opinião é a melhor opção, mas como deve ser feita essa solicitação? (In my opinion is the best option, but such request should be made? by Google Translator)

Comment: Propor edição seguida de uma flag como dupe, ou pelo menos comentar na questão original que se deve fazer uma tradução devido à dupe que existe noutra língua (Propose an edit to the original question and flag the dupe. Or at least comment that the original one needs a translation due to the dupe being in another language)

Answer (score 6):

On German.SE, there's a similar discussion:

> [If the same question is asked in German and English is it a duplicate?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate)

On German.SE it seems to be common practice to leave the question open (and link to its duplicate in the other language) and we could opt to do the same here.

However, if we do, I think we should follow the suggestion of adding a comment with a link to the duplicate in the other language, or better, add a post notice (which may be added by moderators and appears in yellow).

Comment: (I voted "Leave open" until we have reached consensus here.)

Comment: Your final clause ("but  recommended to close the question") makes the stance of this answer unclear to me... If you simply meant to provide a link without endorsing it, a comment would have been more suitable. Anyway, I agree with the "consensus" there that leaving such questions open is best, since Stack Exchange offers no formal way of linking questions without closing one of them (which is undesirable when the language used differs).

Comment: Note that the second most up voted answer there suggests to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Okay, thank you for editing. I usually agree with Cartaino (author of the second answer in that link), but disagree here because "the path to the correct answer" that he speaks of is imaginary, I suspect. People landing from Google do not click through links and should not be expected to.

Comment: Well, there doesn't even seem to be that good of a consensus on German SE.

Comment: @E_net4 Not consensus, but de-facto policy, as far as I can tell. (I haven't been very active there.)

Comment: At the moment the types of "post notices" are limited to `citation needed`, `current event` and `insufficient explanation`. Maybe eventually we could request a "custom post notice" (like a custom close reason), which allows a moderator to mark both posts as translations of each other.

Answer (score -1):

Não creio que deva ser considerada duplicada, vez que a resposta pode de fato variar justamente em virtude da língua.